# Site's section background image in global CSS is not applying for specific page

Tags: community-builder, experience-cloud, experience-builder-page, community-cloud, digital-experience

Using experience cloud builder, I want to apply a banner in section background for 1st section only. And I need it to be device responsive and for different devices the banner image should vary. So, I am tweaking changes in Theme Global CSS. Which was successful but for Home page and other pages I need different sized images. I did write like below. But when I am loading the page all the pages getting the same sized image.

For Home page I used 1600X499 image and for Other pages I used 1600X380 size images. Problem here is for all pages I am getting 1600X499px image only. How to over come it.

````
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .comm-page-home .siteforceThemeLayoutStarter>.body .siteforceDynamicLayout.siteforceContentArea div .ui-widget:first-of-type .cb-section.forceCommunitySection .cb-section_background {
        
        background-image: url('/resource/Homepage_desktop_banner') !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-size: 100% 100% !important;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .comm-page-custom-contact-page .siteforceThemeLayoutStarter>.body .siteforceDynamicLayout.siteforceContentArea div .ui-widget:first-of-type .cb-section.forceCommunitySection .cb-section_background {
        
        background-image: url('/resource/landingpage_desktop_banner') !important;
        background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
        background-size: 100% 100% !important;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: made the changes, please check